# Swift UI - LazyVGrid and ForEach - cannot use duplicate items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach, lazyvgrid

New to SwiftUI and trying to display these emojis on separate CardViews inside of a LazyVGrid. When I use a ForEach loop to set one emoji per CardView, I cannot use duplicate emojis - even though I used `id: \.self` (actually, not entirely sure that matters for what I'm trying to achieve but thought it was worth mentioning).

Basically, I can show 5 cards but, when I try to show 6 (which is when the duplicate items begin), the preview crashes. I can do it with an HStack but, for some reason, cannot with a LazyVStack. I reviewed LazyVStack documentation but couldn't find an answer to this.

Additionally, tried using .indicies in ForEach but didn't seem to fix it either.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var emojis: [String] = ["", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", "",
                            "", "", "", ""]
    @State var emojiCount = 5 //6
    
    var gridLayout = [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout) {
//            HStack {
                ForEach((emojis[0..<emojiCount]), id: \.self) { emoji in
                    CardView(content: emoji)
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)

            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                remove
                Spacer()
                add
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    var add: some View {
        Button(action: {
            emojiCount += 1
        }, label: {
            Text("⨁")
        })
    }

    var remove: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if emojiCount > 0 {
                emojiCount -= 1
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("⊖")
        })
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3.0)
                Text(content)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews_2: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Hello, World!")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have duplicate `id`s for views within `LazyVGrid` (and others such as `List`). Since you have duplicate emojis and you are identifying each `CardView` by `\.self`, you have views with **duplicate** IDs.

#### Solution #1 (worse)

Only use this if you have constant data, otherwise you may get the problems mentioned below.

Use the index. This will always be unique. However, this may cause problems when the `emojis` changes, because views will then be swapping IDs (which breaks animations, etc). The `id`s here are **not** constant.

See solution #2 for a better way.

```
ForEach(0 ..< emojiCount, id: \.self) { emojiIndex in
    CardView(content: emojis[emojiIndex])
}
```

#### Solution #2 (better)

You can use this on constant or mutating data.

Make each emoji uniquely identifiable. This is the **best** solution. The `id`s here **are** constant.

```
struct MyEmoji: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let string: String

    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }
}
```

```
var emojis: [MyEmoji] = [MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""),
                         MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""),
                         MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""),
                         MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""),
                         MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""),
                         MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji(""), MyEmoji("")]
```

```
ForEach(emojis[0 ..< emojiCount]) { emoji in
    CardView(content: emoji.string)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you used indices, but the following worked in my own tests:

```
ForEach(Array((emojis[0..<emojiCount]).enumerated()),id:\.offset) { index,emoji in {
  ....
}
```

I'm not sure why HStack works, but in general, SwiftUI uses ids to track changes so it's a best practice to keep them as close to real identifiers as possible.
In the case where you're using \.self, it uses the emoji string itself which ends up with duplicate ids. There's a WWDC video from this year (2021) explaining the importance of ids and how misuse can cause odd SwiftUI behavior:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Comment: `HStack` works because it doesn't need `id`s as the data is static. `\.offset` is not a great way to uniquely identify each view - if the data changes, views are swapping IDs (which breaks animations, etc). See my answer where I say why trying to uniquely identify views by index isn't a great idea.

Comment: When using `enumerated()` in SwiftUI, you should try id by `\.element` instead - which ends up like my solution #2 in the end anyways, because then each element will need to be `Identifiable`.

Comment: Depends on the usage, no? If there's no plan to insert/remove from the contents (e.g. its a static set of emojis as indicated in the sample code OP gave), then it seems better than wrapping and giving an arbitrary id for every emoji.

Comment: Yeah, if the data is constant this is completely fine - it isn't any different to just identifying by index. This solution is fine for some cases, which is why I gave two methods depending on if the data changes or not. I think it's probably better to assume the data may change, as questions often use static data just to do a quick demo.